# How to completely hide a row from TableLayout in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-tablelayout

The rows with the hours 18, 19, 20, 21 are hidden using the INVISIBLE option. But it still leaves the empty gap at the end. Is there any way to remove that gap as well?

```
private void hideEveningHours() {  // hiding evening rows
    TableRow tr = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row18);
    tr.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    tr = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row19);
    tr.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    tr = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row20);
    tr.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    tr = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row21);
    tr.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

[image: The hours]

Comment: Have you tried setting tr.setVisibility(View.GONE);?

Comment: Not sure what you mean that there's an empty gap at the end. I think it's just part of the background of your app. But like @ZygoteInit noted, `View.GONE` removes them from the View hierarchy, while `View.INVISIBLE` only sets their opacity to zero.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
View.GONE
```

instead of

```
View.INVISIBLE
```

`View.INVISIBLE` only makes the `View` invisible. It is still added to the `View` hierarchy, and space is allocated for it. Whereas `View.GONE` *removes* the `View` from the `ViewGroup` as though it was never present in the first place. What's more, you can get it back simply by setting its visibility to

```
View.VISIBLE
```